# Number of Idempotent matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find number of of Idempotent matrices of order $n$ with entries as only $0$ and $1$ over the field of reals. I tried it for matrices of order 2 its comes 8. Is there any general method to find such types of matrices? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying the matrices are over the field of two elements, or do you just mean matrices over whatever field?

Comment: no no over reals..

Comment: It seems that there is no known general method to count such matrices. See: http://noetherian.net/ERAU/Conference/Abstracts/prescott_talk.pdf

Comment: only abstract is given there...

Comment: @YOGESH note the quote *"No closed formula for the number of idempotent (0,1)-matrices of order $n$ is known yet"*

Comment: But it is said that bounds are there...

Comment: @YOGESH Okay, but this is the first time you're saying that you're interested in bounds (or your earlier comment was deleted).  At any rate, it isn't always so easy to access a current paper.

Comment: @YOGESH you might want to try asking this on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/)

Comment: @YOGESH alternatively, if this is for research, you could try emailing the authors of the original paper.